Different verbs for activism/advocacy
I'm trying to acquire French vocabulary around advocacy. I have found three different verbs used:

Militer, which is frequently used in CBC news articles
Plaidoyer, which I've never seen used, but came up in Google translate
Préconiser, which I've seen used on Construisons Montréal homepage

What are the different connotations of these words? In what situation should one be used over the other?

Note that the second one isn't a verb but a noun (it used to be a verb in Old French though).

Tout se trouve sur un dictionnaire.

manifester is probably the most French way of advocacy ;)

Militer is a verb that describes the actions of an individual (un militant) actively involved in a political party, a trade union, or any advocacy and similar group.
Un plaidoyer (noun) is the speech of a lawyer (also plaidoirie) but can be used for any advocate that defends a cause the same way, i.e. plaide une cause (plaider is the corresponding verb.)
Préconiser is not directly related to activism. An expert préconise something, i.e. provides an advice, a recommendation.

The OP is asking for verbs. You do mention plaidoyer is the "speech of a lawyer" so although you are not explicit about it, one might deduce it is a noun.  Why not mention the corresponding verb.

@None I did use the verb at the end (il plaide une cause). Will make the fact plaidoyer is not a verb clearer.
